# Array initialization error in Verilog

Tags: arrays, initialization, verilog

I made a code like this:

```
input [7:0] Address, WriteData;
input MemRead = 0, MemWrite = 0, CLK;
output reg[7:0] ReadData;

reg [31:0] Input[7:0], Output[7:0];
reg [31:0] Sel;
wire [4:0] addr = Address[4:0];
integer i;

initial begin
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
        Output[i] = i;
        Output[15 + i] = 255 - i + 1;
    end
    Sel = 32'b0;        
end


always @(MemRead or MemWrite) begin
    if(MemRead == 1) begin
        ReadData <= Output[7]; // here is error point
    end
    else if(MemWrite == 1) begin
        Input[addr] <= WriteData;
        Sel[addr] <= MemWrite;
    end
end
```

It initializes array `Output` like:

```
Output[0] = 0, Output[1] = 1, Output[2] = 2...
```

When I gave `ReadData <= Output[number]` with number < 8, and simulate, it gives expected result: `ReadData = 00000111` for `Output[7]`.

But, when I gave number >= 8, result changes: `ReadData = XXXXXXXX` for `Output[8]`.

I did not changed anything but the number. How can this happen?

Answer (score 2):

You declared `Output` as following:

```
reg [31:0] Output[7:0];
```

It means that you have 8 vectors, 32 bits each. Judging by your confusion and one of your loops, I'd say that you want 32 vectors, 8 bits (1 byte) each. In that case, you should declare `Output` as:

```
reg [7:0] Output [31:0];
```

Btw you should rather avoid naming your signals almost like Verilog keywords (input, output, etc)